# How does comparison expressions in numpy arrays work in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I was trying a tutorial in python which had the following piece of code which I am trying to understand:

I have a numpy ndarray X where

```
X=[[ 15  39]
   [ 15  81]
   [ 16   6]
   [ 16  77]
   [ 17  40]
   ....]
```

and another np.ndarray ykmeans of dimension=1 where its length is same as X

```
y_kmeans=[2 3 2 3 2 3 2 0 0 0 3 2 0 2 3 ....]
```

I fail to understand the below line in my code which returns array X with the values of X where y_kmeans array has value equal to 0. (y_kmeans == 0 returns an array of True and False)

```
X[y_kmeans == 0, 0]
```

Can someone please explain how it works and returns only those rows in X where y_kmeans==0 returns a True value.

Comment: Numpy lets you [index with a boolean array](https://www.google.com/search?q=numpy+boolean+index).  What about it?

Comment: @DavisHerring thanks for the direction. I had tried to search for the explanation for the way the above thing works but didn't know about numpy boolean index. One of the SO links from your search link explains it the best so just including [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47118337/boolean-indexing-in-numpy) for others to refer

Comment: Good: then we can mark this as a duplicate of it: [Boolean indexing in NumPy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47118337/boolean-indexing-in-numpy).